# Array push is not working

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am working with Express and mongoose . Don't know why `array.push` is not working . Maybe I am calling it in asynchronous function .

```
function x(){
    var a = [] ;
    database.auth.distinct('tag',function(err , tagname){
        console.log(tagname); // printing tag names perfectly
        a.push(tagname);

    });
       console.log("a =" ,a); // printing an empty array 
    /*for(var x = 0; x< a.length ; x++){  //so this block is not working .
        database.auth.count({ 'tag' : a[x] },function(err, nish){
            // a[tagname[x]] = nish.length ;

        });*/

   // }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `push` method is in a callback that may be executed later ,so you have to check the array there.

```
function x() {
    var a = [];

    database.auth.distinct('tag',function(err , tagname){
        console.log("2");
        console.log(tagname); // printing tag names perfectly
        a.push(tagname);
        console.log("Array length: ", a.length);
    });

    console.log("1");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your array is populated in the callback, so you can list the values from the callback: like here:

```
function x(){
    var a = [] ;
    database.auth.distinct('tag',function(err , tagname){
        console.log(tagname); // printing tag names perfectly
        a.push(tagname);
        console.log("a =" ,a); // 
        for(var x = 0; x< a.length ; x++){  //so this block is not working .
        database.auth.count({ 'tag' : a[x] },function(err, nish){
            // a[tagname[x]] = nish.length ;
        });

    });
       console.log("a =" ,a); // printing an empty array 
    }
```